# Sql server order by for Hebrew column

Tags: sql-server, hebrew

I have this query :

```
Select * from 'mytable' order by 'HebreColumn'
```

HebreColumn is nvarchar type, with hebrew text.

It doesnt sort the table by א,ב,ג

Any idea?

Comment: Check that: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176552%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: And that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933426(v=sql.80).aspx <- To check your sort mode